# Monoid prime ideals and prime congruences

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids, congruences, prime-ideals

I was wondering what the connection is between the notion of "prime congruence" on a monoid, and the notion of "prime ideal" in a monoid. Starting from a prime ideal $P$ in a monoid $M$, one can naturally define a congruence $\sim_P$ from $P$ (the *Reese congruence*), but that doesn't seem to be a prime congruence. Is there another connection ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is a prime congruence?

Comment: The interplay is involved and depends on the nature of the monoid. Maybe you want to read the paper "Congruence schemes" International Journal of Math. Vol. 24, Issue 2 (2013). It deals with a generalisation of monoids, but the monoid case is well included.